# How to install the Boost.CRC library on Debian

Tags: debian, libraries, c++, boost

I need to install the Boost CRC library on Debian 11.7. I've searched in Synaptic Package Manager but did't find it.

Also, I would prefer to install just that specific library (in a minimal configuration), without a vast number of additional Boost packages and libraries, if possible.

Comment: it's part of libboost1 - which is a lot of other stuff - but crc library does depend on much of the rest of the boost library ... so, I don't think you can install "just boost crc" unless you do it manually from boost source

Comment: I already have some Boost libraries installed (libboost-filesystem1.74.0,
libbbost-iostreams1.74.0, libboost-locale1.74.0, libboost-regex1.74.0, libboost-thread1.74.0) - by default, or as application dependencies.

Comment: To develop you also need the -dev package. For an example use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573726/how-to-use-boostcrc

Comment: not to develop - the compile ready project, the compiler requires  `#include <boost/crc.hpp>` which is missing in my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need a specific Boost library, just the headers:

```
sudo apt install libboost1.74-dev
```

Compiling [the Boost example CRC program](https://sources.debian.org/src/boost1.74/1.74.0%2Bds1-21.1/libs/crc/crc_example.cpp/) produces a functional binary with the following dependencies:

```
$ ldd crc_example
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff22763000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f71b878b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f71b8771000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f71b85ac000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f71b8468000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f71b899f000)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed. Now the sources compiles fine.Thank you!